# ¿como puedo envíar una notificación desde un usuario a otro usando dbus?

Tags: python, linux

En un proyecto que estoy desarrollando, necesito que un script ejecutado desde polkit pueda mostrar una notificación al usuario cuando se capture el evento requerido.

El problema es que el usuario que polkit usa para ejecutar sus scripts, llamado `polkitd`, es de tipo **nologin**, con lo cual no puede cambiar de usuario para lanzar la notificación

Por ello, quiero crear un servidor dbus, al cual estaría suscrito un cliente ejecutado con el usuario. `polkitd` enviaría el mensaje a través del servidor, y el usuario lo recibiría a traves del cliente, para finalmente mostrarlo por pantalla en forma de notificación.

He visto este ejemplo que me podría ser útil, con un cliente y servidor escritos en Python (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390064/use-dbus-to-just-send-a-message-in-python/)

Pero, si ejecuto el servidor como otro usuario, el cliente no es capaz de acceder al bus para recibir el mensaje.

¿como podría solucionarlo?

ACTUALIZACIÓN:

Tras probar cambiando el bus del usuario (SessionBus() ) al del sistema (SystemBus() ), parece que el sistema me está restringiendo el acceso a dicho bus, y no me permite utilizarlo.

El error mostrado dice:

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied:    Connection ":1.69" is not allowed to own the service "org.preminder" due to security policies in the configuration file
```

`org.preminder` es el nombre que le he puesto al bus.

Siguiendo esta guía(https://georgemuraruc.wordpress.com/2015/07/16/d-bus-tutorial-for-python/) he encontrado una forma de otorgar permisos a usuarios para que accedan al bus. Lo he probado, ejecutando el servidor como root, y funciona, pero no sé si es una buena manera de resolverlo.

Además, veo que esta implementación no permite al cliente mantenerse a la espera de un nuevo mensaje sino que, si el cliente se ejecuta y no hay ningún mensaje, éste simplemente falla.

El código actual está aquí: https://github.com/AlmuHS/Pendrive_Reminder/tree/work-in-progress/dbus-server

Comment: No es necesario cambiar el titulo para indicar que ha sido resuelto, basta que una respuesta sea marcada como correcta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El ejemplo que mencionas es válido, con la salvedad de que en ese ejemplo están usando el bus de sesión (*session bus*), que es utilizado para comunicar procesos dentro de la sesión del usuario. Como necesitas comunicar un servicio con una aplicación del usuario, el bus que debes usar es el de sistema (*system bus*).

https://pythonhosted.org/txdbus/dbus_overview.html

El equivalente al ejemplo mencionado pero usando el bus de sistema sería el siguiente (únicamente cambiando la línea `bus = dbus.SessionBus` por `bus = dbus.SystemBus()`):

```
import dbus,gtk
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
bus = dbus.SystemBus()
def msg_handler(*args,**keywords):
    try:
        msg=str(keywords['path'][8:])
        #...do smthg with msg
        print msg
    except:
        pass

bus.add_signal_receiver(handler_function=msg_handler, dbus_interface='my.app', path_keyword='path')
gtk.main()
```

De la misma manera, al comando dbus-send habría que pasarle el parámetro `--system` en lugar de `--session`:

```
dbus-send --system /my/app/this_is_the_message my.app.App
```

Comment: En realidad me estoy basando en la implementación de este comentario, que no usa el comando que mencionas

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22394122/7077301

Estoy haciendo pruebas cambiando al bus del sistema, y creo que necesito un fichero .service

Comment: Finalmente, me funcionó con el cliente que has puesto.